# How to use ResizeObserver to check only body's width change in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, resize-observer

I want to check `<body>`'s width change (not height).

Is there a way to do so with ResizeObserver?

Comment: you can do with ViewPort.innerWidth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth, basically body is viewport

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example. Read more documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver.

```js
function handleWidthChange (width) {
  console.log(width);
}

let prevWidth = 0;

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const width = entry.borderBoxSize?.[0].inlineSize;
    if (typeof width === 'number' && width !== prevWidth) {
      prevWidth = width;
      handleWidthChange(width);
    }
  }
});

observer.observe(document.body, {box: 'border-box'});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, may I know what is the meaning of `?` in the `entry.borderBoxSize?.[0].inlineSize`?

Comment: It is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). `width` will be `undefined` if that property is not present on the [ResizeObserverEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry) (rather than throwing a TypeError when trying to access the first array member). If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as such.

Comment: thanks. just note that html-minify-terser fails to recognize it. lol